# Pandas Groupby with Function that Combine Similar Index

Tags: pandas

I'm using Pandas groupby to analysis client data but there is no specified client ID.
So I have to groupby client name but some similar client names are actually same one.
I want to using a function that can combine similar client name which have the same first five chars,just like this but with modify the index name
I'm first posting, thanks!

---

*********UPDATA*************
I tried to get a correct namelist first. and use dataframe.apply method to correct col['FHRMC'],but my data is about 150,0000+rows and namelist is about 2500+, I run this script without Error occurred and also running hours with no result.
some of my code below:

```
def groupData(path):

    df = pd.read_csv(path,error_bad_lines=False)

    list_raw_FHRMC =list(df.groupby(df['ZKFHRMC']),'ZKRKRQ0'].indices.keys()) 

    deduped_list = deduped_FHRMC(list_raw_FHRMC)


 **grouped_data.apply(correct_FHRMC,nameList=deduped_list,axis=1).groupby(df['ZKFHRMC'])['ZKJF001','ZKZZL00','ZKZLC00','ZKRKRQ0']**
```

## something wrony with this line↑

```
    concated_data = concateValueF_and_A(grouped_data)

    return concated_data


def deduped_FHRMC(nameList):  # I want to use this func to get a namelist

    for name in nameList:
        if nameList.index(name) == len(nameList)-1:
            break
        if len(name) == 3 or len(name) == 2:
            if len(name) == 3 and name[:3] == nameList[nameList.index(name)+1][:3]:  #3个字的人名
                nameList.pop(nameList.index(name)+1)
            if name[:2] == nameList[nameList.index(name)+1][:2]:  #2个字的人名
                nameList.pop(nameList.index(name)+1)
        else:
            if name[:5] == nameList[nameList.index(name)+1][:5]:  #5个字的发货人，通常会是公司名称
                nameList.pop(nameList.index(name)+1)
    return nameList


def correct_FHRMC(r,nameList): #更正发货人名称
    for name in nameList:
        if name[:5] in r['ZKFHRMC']:
            r['ZKFHRMC'] = name
    return r
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow, Instead of posting your code as image, please provide editable text, so that it will be easy to copy and test your code,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to add a column to your DataFrame that has the groupby key, then use the column to perform the groupby.

In your scenario, you apply your lambda to column A. Then groupby on the result. Something like:

```
df["C"] = df["A"].map(lambda x: x[0:5])
df.groupby("C")
```

Comment: def dedupeName(r):
    r['FHRMC_key'] = re.split("-|<",r['FHRMC_key'])[0][:6]
    return r